# Make volumetric mist finer - and perhaps even let it drift a little?

Tags: volumetrics

On the advise of several youtube-tutorials, I made mist with the following setup

[image: Mist-setup in node-editor "world"]

But as you can see here, the mist is rather lumpy, and since it doesn't drift, it doesn't really look like mist.

[image]

Questions:

How can I make the mist finer, less lumpy?

How could I make the mist drift slowly?

UPDATE

The first image is rendered with 128 samples in 16 seconds, the second with 1024 samples in 1 mins 59.44 seconds.

[image: 256 samples rendered in 16 seconds]

[image: 1024 samples rendered in 2 minuttes]

Comment: I guess the grainy texture is caused by the sampling low resolution for the viewport, maybe check the settings. As for the drift, you need to give your Principled Volume a texture like a Noise Texture and move it with a Mapping node

Comment: The lumpiness is denoising artifacts.  The way you have it set up it will have a uniform density if you let it render long enough.  You would have to attach some texture to the density socket and animate with a mapping node as suggested by @moonboots

Comment: Thnx. I've added two renders to my post, one with 128 samples and one with 1024. It's very clear that more samples is helping, but what a hit to rendertimes: 16 secs vs. 1:59.44 mins!

Comment: yes but have you enabled a denoising? it may be the problem as Allen suggested

Comment: No, I thought that denoising was necessary. But u're right: when I turn it off, the mist looks a lot better, with no drastic increase in rendertime!